# Why do dogs howl?

Tags: dogs, behavior, psychology, vocalizations

I am wondering if dogs only howl due to fear or as [learned behaviour](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/477/why-does-my-dog-sing-along-to-final-jeopardy).

Are there other reasons a dog would howl?

Is loneliness or other emotions a factor?

Comment: Please mind that if you have specific issue related to howling of your dog(s), you could expand your question by including their description and I would try answering them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Howling is an ancestral trait in dogs because dogs and wolves share a common ancestor; and yes, there could be many reasons for this behavior and it's usually completely natural; it's just a type of dog's vocalization, like barking. It's hard to tell exact reason without the context and details because there could be as many potential reasons for howling as there could be for barking. It could happen, for example, as a response to specific sounds, for attention, and communication. Loneliness or emotional distress mentioned by you could be valid reasons as well.